# Rest API in VBA Macros

Tags: vba, get, rest

When i wrote a http get request in vba to get the session id , instead of getting the session id , i am getting an HTML code in the immediate window?
Why is this so?

Comment: Could you please share the code you tried to run?

Comment: You're probably using `Debug.Print <<httpReq>>.ResponseText` instead of parsing the response headers. The session ID will be in a header, not the body of the response.

Answer (score 0):

So basically , when you open the link on browser it will first ask the user to enter his username and password , then it will show him the session id.
But when i select the link in vba code , it shows me the html code

Sub Button1_Click()

```
Dim objRequest As Object
Dim strUrl As String
Dim blnAsync As Boolean
Dim strResponse As String

Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
strUrl = "url to be entered"
blnAsync = True

With objRequest
    .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .Send
    'spin wheels whilst waiting for response
    While objRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    strResponse = .ResponseText
End With

Debug.Print strResponse
```

End Sub